# Practical way to convert jupyter notebook to MS Word document?

Tags: python, jupyter

What would be a practical way to convert a Jupyter Notebook to a Word document (.doc) ? I am asking this in a professional context, so I'd like to avoid manual solutions, do it in an efficient way (fast), avoid third parties... etc. Something that works like Rmarkdown to produce .doc would be very welcome.

Comment: I hope this blog will guide/help you to get the answer. Link: https://blog.ouseful.info/2017/06/13/using-jupyter-notebooks-for-assessment-export-as-word-docx-extension/

Comment: Got a medal for 10k views and feel like the currently accepted answer is not practical enough. So I've added a bounty. I don't know what is the etiquette about changing the accepted answer so I'll leave it like that untill it is clarified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably using a method similarly to what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334261/9435355), that is, convert the notebook to markdown and then use any of the tools available (such as [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/)) to convert the markdown to a Word document.

Comment: I did see that question (and answer), but couldn't find a way to convert .md from python. It appears that pypandoc would do the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

#### [Jupyter Notebooks For Assessment – Export as Word (.docx) Extension](https://blog.ouseful.info/2017/06/13/using-jupyter-notebooks-for-assessment-export-as-word-docx-extension/).

The only challenge with this post is that it's a bit confusing and cumbersome since it requires you to deal with an extension. Despite that, in the code provided in the post one only needs two commands to run in order to convert the **jupyter notebook file (ipynb)** to **word (docx)**.

Before that, make sure you have [jupyter nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) and [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/getting-started.html#) set up

To convert the **jupyter notebook** to **word**, first, we need to convert the notebook to `html`. You can perform these commands from cmd, `powershell` or `terminal` on `mac`.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html your_notebook_name.ipynb
```

After execution will create `HTML` version of your notebook and will save it in the current working directory. You will see one html file will be added into the current directory with `your_notebook_name.html` name

`(your_notebook_name.ipynb --> your_notebook_name.html)`

Then we need to convert `html` file generated to `word (docx)`

```
pandoc -s my_notebook.html -o my_notebook.docx
```